# Radio button in JSTL and Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, el

I have a few values at JSP file, and I there is a problem with pushing radio button to the Servlet and outputting it.

The input file is in this jsp:

```
<label for="phone">Phone: </label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="${phone}"><br/><br/>

    <input type="radio" name="sex" id="sex" value="${male}">Male
    <input type="radio" name="sex" id="sex" value="${female}"/>Female<br/><br/>
```

And Servler is here:  `public static RequestNewEmployee fromRequestParameters(HttpServletRequest request) {
            return new RequestNewEmployee(
                    request.getParameter("firstName"),
                    request.getParameter("lastName"),
                    request.getParameter("email"),
                    request.getParameter("phone"),
                    request.getParameter("sex"));
        }
        public void setAsRequestAttributes(HttpServletRequest request) {
            request.setAttribute("firstName", firstName);
            request.setAttribute("lastName", lastName);
            request.setAttribute("email", email);
            request.setAttribute("phone", phone);
            request.setAttribute("sex", sex);
        }`

However, I don't receive any praramentr at sex field( throught all others work properly). What might be an issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Theory**
${} is called EL expression. Inside you can have variables. From [the oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html):

> The web container evaluates a variable that appears in an expression
>   by looking up its value according to the behavior of
>   PageContext.findAttribute(String). For example, when evaluating the
>   expression ${product}, the container will look for product in the
>   page, request, session, and application scopes and will return its
>   value. If product is not found, null is returned. A variable that
>   matches one of the implicit objects described in Implicit Objects will
>   return that implicit object instead of the variable's value.

---

Now lets talk about your problem.

1. You can't have two html tags with identical ids.
2. You receive empty parameter because, obviously, it's empty(undefined). Where did you define `male` and `female` variables?

I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

**form.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/formServlet">
        <input type="radio" name="sex" id="sexChoice1" value="male">Male
        <input type="radio" name="sex" id="sexChoice2" value="female"/>Female<br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**FormServlet**

```
public class FormServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        System.out.println(req.getParameter("sex"));
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FormServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.artmal.controller.FormServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FormServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/formServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Console output after selecting 'male' option and submitting:

> male